# How to find exact number or word using preg_match(), or another way

Tags: php, regex

After a lot of time finding some examples around the web without success, i came here... So, i'm using this code to find exact word:

```
preg_match("/\b".$searched."\b/i", file_get_contents("mytextfile1.txt"))
```

This works fine with letters/characters, but when i use a nuber as 005, 087, 172 the IF condition return always FALSE... below, two examples:

Working examples:

```
$searched = "someword";
if ( preg_match("/\b".$searched."\b/i", file_get_contents("mytextfile1.txt")) ) {
// TRUE
}
```

NON working example:

```
$searched = "047";
if ( preg_match("/\b".$searched."\b/i", file_get_contents("mytextfile1.txt")) ) {
// FALSE
}
```

The .TXT file contain many strings like this:

```
somenametofind|alinktoimages_icon_047_00.png|some-text
```

Please, can you tell me what is wrong in that regex? And how can i solve it?
I hope you are understand my problem... thanks a lot in advance. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that `\b` matches any non-word character i.e. `[^A-Za-z0-9_]`. Note that `_` *is* considered to be a word character, so `\b047\b` will not match `_047_`. If you want to exclude `_` from your "words", change your regex to

```
"/(^|[^A-Za-z0-9])$searched([^A-Za-z0-9]|$)/i"
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/q7KCu)

If you want to allow words to include `_`, it might be simpler to change the boundaries when searching for numbers. For example:

```
$string = 'somenametofind|alinktoimages_icon_047_00.png|some-text';
$searched = array("some-text", "047");
foreach ($searched as $s) {
    $b = is_numeric($s) ? '\D' : '\b';
    if (preg_match("/$b$s$b/i", $string) ) {
        echo "found $s\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
found some-text
found 047
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/ALlvv)

Comment: Additionally the backslash needs to be masked!

Comment: @csabinho not in PHP

Comment: `"/(^|[^A-Za-z0-9])".$searched."([^A-Za-z0-9]|$)/i"` <-- With your last edit, it works perfect!

Comment: `"/[^A-Za-z0-9]".$searched."[^A-Za-z0-9]/i"` <-- This one instead, does not work well :(

Comment: @Devilix no - because the `[^A-Za-z0-9]` won't match start or end of line. That's why it needs to be grouped with `^` at the start and `$` at the end

Comment: @Nick Thanks a lot bro! regex are very difficult for me... :( Many many thanks again! :)